# Axios PUT request doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

axios.put method doesn't work while axios.post works.

This is working example for post request. (example)

```
let response = await axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/urls/url/`, {
    post_id,
    password,
    content
  }, { headers });
  console.log(response.status) // 201.
```

I just copied and pasted the valid post request, and modified some fields and method for `put` request. But it returns 400 error on server side.

```
let response = await axios.put(`${ROOT_URL}/profile/update/`, {
    title,
    gender
  }, { headers }); <- Server prints 400 HTTP error.
```

I tested with `Postman` and I confirmed that it works with put method. I have to think that my syntax for axios.put is wrong but I'm not sure how it can be different with the post method.

If you see axios's official doc page, it looks almost identical. [Axios documentation link](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config-1)

And axios version is 0.16.2 : `"axios": "^0.16.2",`

Comment: I'd make sure the server is expecting an object similar to `{title: 'title', gender: 'gender'}` as that's what your second parameter expands to. Also, could you post code showing what your headers object looks like?

Comment: I would try to see what's going on in the server code when it hits the endpoint.

Comment: YEAH you were right. I put the gender with 'u' and it printed 400. The reason was that I set my backend gender field to choose specific string value. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Um... should I delete the question ??? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

400 is bad request not 405 method not allowed.

I'd check what your posting is correct.

Is this a valid object?

```
{
    title,
    gender
}
```

Example:

```
axios.put('/api/something', {
    foo: bar
})
    .then(function (response) {
        // do something...
    }.bind(this))
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

Comment: It's a valid object assuming your environment supports es6 [(docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

Comment: why do you `.bind(this))` ?

Comment: @Sua Morales, copied and pasted from my code, i needed access to the outer scope in success handler, not needed in this example

Answer (score 1):

I post this here maybe it answers someone's problem

if in your api setup in the backend. the route is configured like this 
`'api/user1 or some other mode of identification/someData/anotherData'`

you should send the data exactly as such and not as an object.
so in my case it was like this:
`` axios.put(`${Routes.ConfrimCode}${phoneNum}/${imei}/${code}`).then(res=>{
    //callback
}) ``